# Android MediaSessionCompat not showing Media Control Buttons on KitKat

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I'm building a music player and am currently trying to implement Lockscreen Media Controls and playback information. My first attempt was with a RemoteControlClient but this method is being deprecated and I ran into a bug I was unable to solve. So I attempted to switch to the MediaSessionCompat class, everything works except media controls don't show up.

```
    ComponentName eventReceiver = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), RemoteMediaReceiver.class.getName());
    Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    mediaButtonIntent.setComponent(eventReceiver);
    PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "TAG", eventReceiver, mediaPendingIntent);
    mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
            Log.d("MediaSession", "onMediaButtonEvent");
            return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            Log.d("MediaSession", "onPlay");
            super.onPlay();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            Log.d("MediaSession", "onPause");
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToNext() {
            Log.d("MediaSession", "onSkipToNext");
            super.onSkipToNext();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToPrevious() {
            Log.d("MediaSession", "onSkipToPrevious");
            super.onSkipToPrevious();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(long pos) {
            Log.d("MediaSession", String.format("onSeekTo %d", pos));
            super.onSeekTo(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            Log.d("MediaSession", "onStop");
            super.onStop();
        }
    });
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(playbackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_STOPPED, PlaybackStateCompat.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 0));
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
```

This is how I setup my Media Session then I have helper methods that update it's state and metadata like so

```
public void start(){
    mControl.setPlaying(true);
    notify(State.PLAY);
    if(!audioFocus) requestFocus();
    //remoteCC.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING, mp.getCurrentPosition(), 1.0f);
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(playbackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, mp.getCurrentPosition(), 1));
    mediaSession.setActive(true);
    mp.start();
}
public void pause(){
    mControl.setPlaying(false);
    notify(State.PAUSE);
    //remoteCC.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PAUSED);
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(playbackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, mp.getCurrentPosition(), 0));
    mediaSession.setActive(true);
    mp.pause();
}
public void mediaSessionNewSong(){
    Song song = mControl.getSongSet().safeCurrent();
    Bitmap bitmap = AlbumArtCache.instance().get(song.album_id);
    if(bitmap == null) bitmap = AlbumArtCache.instance().get(-1);
    MediaMetadataCompat.Builder metadata = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();
    metadata.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, song.album);
    metadata.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, song.artist);
    metadata.putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TRACK_NUMBER, song.track);
    metadata.putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, song.title);
    metadata.putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, song.duration);
    metadata.putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), false));
    mediaSession.setMetadata(metadata.build());
    mediaSession.setActive(true);
}
```

The kicker is, I can get the RemoteControlClient manually with getRemoteControlClient() and set it's transport control flags to make the buttons show up but then they don't use the callback class provided, they use the eventReceiver and I run into the bug I had with my original RemoteClientControl implementation. What am I not seeing? All the documentation I've read and other SO questions I've seen suggest this should work.

EDIT:
Yes, my apologies it's a large codebase so I forgot all my helper methods

```
public PlaybackStateCompat playbackState(int state, long position, float playbackSpeed){
    return new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO)
            .setState(state, position, playbackSpeed)
            .build();
}
```

I updated my library from 22.0.0 to 22.2.1 and now the buttons show up (progress :D), but it would seem the remote client control is using the eventReceiver instead of the MediaSession's callback, except for seekTo which uses the callback as expected.

Comment: Can you include the code for `playbackState()`, particularly the part where you call [setActions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/PlaybackStateCompat.Builder.html#setActions(long))

Comment: Also, are you using the latest version of the Support Library (currently `22.2.1`)?